# How to determine the total memory allocation?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have gone through a C project to understand some concepts and found the following code.

```
#define MY_NODE_ALLOC(coffee) ((struct items *)(coffee) + 1)

struct store
{
  char *name;
  int   id;
};

struct items
{
  char *itemName
  char *itemCode;
  int   quantity;
};

void * allocation(struct store *shop)
{
  struct items *coffee = malloc(sizeof(struct items) + sizeof(*shop));
  return MY_NODE_ALLOC(coffee);
}
```

I have the following questions

1. How much total memory is allocated? is it equal to size of `*shop` and `struct items`?
2. What is the difference between the 2 statements `malloc(sizeof(struct itmes));` and `malloc(sizeof(*shop));`
3. What is this macro returning? As per my understanding, adding 1 to pointer is used to jump to next element in array but I do not understand this case.

Answer (score 2):

> *1- How much total memory is allocated ? is it equal to size of `*shop` and `struct items` ?*

Yes, total size together, in bytes, in case `malloc()` is success.

> *2- What is the difference between the 2 statements `malloc(sizeof(struct itmes));` and `malloc(sizeof(*shop));`*

Two statements allocate different amount of memory, in success case.

- `malloc(sizeof(struct itmes));` allocates as many bytes as of the size of `struct itmes` in bytes.
- `malloc(sizeof(*shop);` allocates as many bytes as of the size of `*shop` (`struct store`) in bytes.

> *3- What is this macro returning ? As per my understanding adding 1 to pointer is used to jump to next element in array but i dont understand this case.*

Yes, you're right. First they are casting the pointer to `struct items *` type, and then incrementing the pointer to point to next memory address of type `struct items *`. To clarify, let's quote `C11`, chapter §6.5.6

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the
>   result has the type of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of
>   an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from
>   the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original
>   array elements equals the integer expression.[....]

Comment: The total allocation is _at least as large as_ the value provided (when successful); in practice it's always more (for malloc overhead) and ignoring malloc overhead it's still probably more (for alignment issues).

Comment: @mah True in general, but not mentioned in the standard. C11/7.22.3.4 _The malloc function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size_ ....

Comment: Malloc also grabs memory off the OS is larger chunks to limit the context switching.

Comment: @mah Just to clarify, my answer is from the _application_ perspective, not from _OS_ perspective. :)

Comment: I think you meant that to be a response to EdHeal instead, who addressed the OS page size aspect that I failed to include.

Comment: I should add a bit of explanation. Malloc manages heap memory. Sometimes it grabs it off the OS or gives it back. But its objective is to limit the context switches. I.e. limit asking the OS for more or less. So when a program asks for a 10 chars of memory it may already have it. If not, why bother the OS for 10 chars. Ask for a page, Then malloc needs housekeeping. So that is some overhead